# Bootstrap vertical positioning to horizontal in smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap for responsive design.

This is the view for computer:
[image]

This is the view on ipad:
[image]

Is it possible to somehow when I change to iPad to change these vertical menu boxes to horizontal state like this:

[image]

I use this classes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">MENU</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">LIST</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

Look at here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities  **The DOC**

**The col-lg is for Large Device**

For extra small device :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">MENU</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">LIST</div>
</div>
```

For small device:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">MENU</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">LIST</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE :**
I don't know what device is IPAD (extrasmall, small or medium device so in my example it will be small..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">MENU
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">acccount</div>
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">transact</div>
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">details</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">LIST</div>
</div>
```

When you see `<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">acccount</div>` :

this div will be 4/12 on small device, and 12/12 (of col-md-4) in medium device...

I hope we are on the same wave now ^^

Comment: Maybe we didn't understand each other. I want vertical menu for big devices, but when I go to iPad size I want these 3 boxes from MENU to be horizontal above LIST.